# Cómo filtrar datos por rango de fechas

Tags: php, mysqli

En una tabla almaceno EVENTOS. Los mismos entre diversas formas de definirlos, tienen una "fecha desde" y una "fecha hasta". Esto puede ser porque quizás un seminario empieza el lunes 17 de julio y termina el 20 de julio.
Ahora bien, en una página tengo una tabla que la cargo con un query que hago sobre esa tabla.

```
$diaActual = date_default_timezone_set("America/Buenos_Aires");
$diaActual = date("Y-m-d");

echo $diaActual;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM eventos WHERE (fec_dde >= $diaActual or fec_hta <= $diaActual) and eve_apr=1 ORDER BY fec_dde asc";
$resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

Esto no estaría funcionando... 
la idea es que si la fecha actual está dentro de las fechas de desarrollo del evento, se muestre el mismo... 
caso contrario que no lo muestre (bah, eso lo hace el query)
obviamente tendrían que quedar visibles los eventos a futuro...

---

EN MYSQL FUNCIONA ESTO:
Me alcanzaría con analizar la "fecha hasta" por lo tanto, en mySQL funciona esta consulta (me trae lo que necesito)

```
SELECT * FROM `eventos` WHERE fec_hta >= '2017/07/10'
```

Pero cuando la llevo a PHP no funciona... alguien puede explicarme por que ?

[image: CAMPOS]

[image: COMO SE VE EN LA APP]

[image: MYSQL]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El formato de la fecha en PHP debe ser igual al usado en la base de datos

```
$diaActual = date("Y/m/d");

SELECT * FROM `eventos` WHERE fec_hta >= '".$diaActual"';
```

Y para que esté entre las dos fechas debe cumplir las 2 condiciones

```
SELECT * FROM `eventos` WHERE fec_hta >= '".$diaActual"' AND fec_dde<= '".$diaActual."';
```

Comment: "SELECT * FROM eventos WHERE (fec_hta >= '$diaActual') ORDER BY fec_dde ASC exacto... veía que me faltaban las comillas simples... pero no me toma el ORDER BY...

Comment: Es un campo DATE? Puede dar error si es texto

Comment: fec_dde es un campo date...

Comment: No se me ocurre dónde puede estar el problema, puedes poner un ejemplo de la tabla?

Comment: AHI SUBI imagenes... primero como esta definida la tabla, despues como se ve en la pagina web y por ultimo como me devuelve mysql el query

Comment: Pues debería ordenar, no se me ocurre porqué no lo hace. Si ordenas por fecha hasta también falla?

Comment: todavía no probe... pruebo en unos minutos

Comment: creo que tengo un problema de formatos de fecha...

Answer (score 1):

Yo creo que te faltan los apostrofes (') encerrando la fecha como lo haces en MySQL. Deberias poner el error para saber que cosa es lo que te da, pero a primera vista intenta lo que te digo.

Comment: si... vi que me faltaba eso... pero el order by lo ignora... "ORDER BY fec_dde ASC"

Comment: No comprendo bien tu último comentario pero asumo que mencionas de porque el `ORDER BY` ignora los apóstrofes. Bueno la respuesta es que ahí va el nombre del campo de una la tabla por lo que deseas ordenar y no una cadena con el valor de una fecha como es el otro caso